# How do I convert a RectTransform (UI Panel) to screen coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to determine the screen coordinates of a RectTransform in Unity3D. How is this done, taking into consideration that the element may be anchored, or even scaled?

I am trying to use RectTransform.GetWorldCorners and then converting each Vector3 to screen coordinates, but the values are wrong.

```
public Rect GetScreenCoordinates(RectTransform uiElement)
{
    var worldCorners = new Vector3[4];
    uiElement.GetWorldCorners(worldCorners);
    var result = new Rect(
        worldCorners[0].x,
        worldCorners[0].y,
        worldCorners[2].x - worldCorners[0].x,
        worldCorners[2].y - worldCorners[0].y);
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        result[index] = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(result[index]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am being stalked and downvoted by someone pathetic. You know, your behaviour just puts people off using this website, and considering I often post answers to my own questions having me delete my questions and leave wouldn't be beneficial to the site's users.

Comment: +10 million for posting answers to your own questions! You are A Good Human™

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the help says that it returns coordinates in world space, they are actually in screen space (at least when the UI is not in world space). So the solution is simple:

```
public Rect GetScreenCoordinates(RectTransform uiElement)
{
  var worldCorners = new Vector3[4];
  uiElement.GetWorldCorners(worldCorners);
  var result = new Rect(
                worldCorners[0].x,
                worldCorners[0].y,
                worldCorners[2].x - worldCorners[0].x,
                worldCorners[2].y - worldCorners[0].y);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: In case that someone is wondering how to get the anchor point in screen coordinates (useful for a mouse) just add the following before returning the result

result .position += result .size * uiElement.pivot;